# Is it ok to pass `int *[LENGTH]` instead `int [][LENGTH]`?

Tags: c++

I have to add new features to old code. The old code have a problem, there are lot of functions which gets arrays as argument, something like this `f(int x[][MAX_LENGTH])`. So I wan't to ask is it ok (standard) to pass `int *[MAX_LENGTH]` instead? In other words is the code bellow standart?

```
# include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void f(int x[][3])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
            cout << x[i][j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    typedef int v3 [3];
    v3 *x;
    x = new v3 [2];
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
            x[i][j] = i * 3 + j; 

    f(x);

    delete [] x;
    return 0;
}
```

**edit** please point the paragraph of standard document if the answer of the question is "YES".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question doesn't match your code, `x` in `main` has type `int (*)[3]`, not `int *[3]`. In this instance the parentheses are important becuase the first is a pointer to an array and the second is an array of pointers.

Your function call `f(x)` is valid because your function declaration is equivalent to

```
void f(int (*x)[3])
```

Function parameters declared as arrays are converted to the equivalent pointer type. (ISO/IEC 14882:2003 8.3.5 [dcl.fct] / 3 )

`x` in `main` has type `v3*`, which expanding the `typedef` is `int (*)[3]` which is exactly the type required by `f`.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler rewrites `f(int x[][MAX_LENGTH])` as `f(int (*x)[MAX_LENGTH])` which is different from `f(int *x[MAX_LENGTH])`. The former is a pointer to an array, the latter is an array of pointers.

Comment: However, in the example the type of `x` really is `int (*)[3]`.  So the example is correct - it doesn't even require a conversion on function argument `x`.

Comment: @asch: Mihran was specifically asking if he could rewrite the parameter as `int *[MAX_LENGTH]`. My answer is no, because that would change the semantics.